# Document is not updated after check in from Word

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, ms-office, checkin

one of our customers has great problems checking in documents to a SharePoint library form Word 2007. Whenever she check's in a document to the library the meta data as version number and checkin comment are updated but not the document itself.

The library is configured in such a way that versioning is activated and documents have to be checked out before editing.

I think it has to do with some Office 2007 or OS settings as every other of her colleges can check in documents without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into a similar issue. The document may be getting uploaded but some sort of caching or proxy issue is causing an older version to appear when you try to download it.

To isolate the issue I suggest you try uploading a text file a couple of times.

Not sure if you'll have access to the component that is actually causing the problem, but as a workaround renaming the file should help.

Comment: It seems as the upload process itself is the problem as everybody else could upload a document which is then available in the doc lib for everyone.